# Ruby/Rails cast as string error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

i am using the parseexcel gem to read an excel file..
every thing is working fine as long as i am printing stuff to the console.
i created a rake task to insert the data to the db..
so i have a bunch of create statements. like this

```
description = row[i+1].to_s
Coa.create(:is_group => true, :ag_gl_code => "AGL_001", :description => "#{description}")
```

my problem is with the 'description' variable.  its a string field. if i print description to the console like this it works and prints the value

```
puts "{#description}" #prints the value 'Estate'
```

but in the create it gives me an sql error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'E":
```

but the query is generated fine. the string is in the query with a single quote, and if the replace the variable with a hard coded string it works just fine. i have tried many combinations, like using to_s etc.. but can't get it to work.

any help would be appreciated. thanks

here is my schema

```
create_table "coas", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "ag_gl_code"
  t.string   "description"
  t.boolean  "is_group"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

here is the terminal log, i have logged the value of 'description', note that it prints the value, and no additional quotes.

```
Estate
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'E": INSERT INTO "coas" ("created_at", "is_group" , "description", "ag_gl_code", "updated_at") VALUES ('2011-07-14 14:48:56.616150', 't', 'Estate', 'AGL_001', '2011-07-14 14:48:56.616150')
```

Comment: Why are you interpolating the string like `:description => "#{description}"`? Just `:description => description` should be sufficient. And your error message indicates that someone isn't quoting things properly.

Comment: `puts "{#description}"` typo?

Comment: i tried :description => description, gave the same error, but if i put :description => 'estate', it works fine. (the puts was a type i made here)

Comment: i have added the schema and the terminal log.

Comment: And what happens if you try that INSERT from the `sqlite3` command line tool?

Comment: yea only estate, if i hard code the something in the create like :description => "value", it works fine.

Comment: if i use the query generated by the error in the sqlite3 tool, it works without any errors, now this is really confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i fixed it. finally.

```
description.to_s("latin1")
```

it was a problem with sqlite encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your `description` variable contains the string `"'Estate'"`. Please note the single quotes.
That's probably the reason for the SQL query to fail.

You can solve this, by removing the quotes from the `description` string:

```
description = row[i+1].to_s[1..-2]
```

If the above fails (maybe your data contains some fields not surrounded by single quotes) the following regex may work better:

```
description = row[i+1].to_s.match(/'(.*)'/)[1]
```

**EDIT:** If you need the single quotes in your database, you'll probably have to escape the single quotes.

Comment: there are no additional quotes so ur first snippet removes part of the  string. the second one gives a cryptic error. :S

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
Coa.create(:is_group => true, :ag_gl_code => "AGL_001", :description => description)
```

or this

```
Coa.create(:is_group => true, :ag_gl_code => "AGL_001", :description => h(description))
```

Comment: first one i tried before gives the same error, second one says h is undefined.